# How to make a curved pattern line in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, line-art

I'm not really sure what else to call it, but my goal basically is to create various locations on a map and have them connect with a curved progress bar-like line.

Like this:
[image: Sample]

I'm familiar with the pen tool and how to make curved lines, but I'm not really sure how to go from a curved line to the picture above.

Comment: this is called a 'pattern brush', you define (or pick) a pattern and apply it to a path as a stroke. Google 'pattern brush' and you'll fond lots of ways how to make and apply them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Bakabaka, but I believe Pattern Brushes are only for Illustrator, no? I'm specifically trying to do this in Photoshop :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't see, please specify in your question. You might be in for a toughie, then. The entire image screams 'vector' to me, and I'm not sure you can reproduce the effect in Ps somewhat easily.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've updated the question :)

Comment: You *can't* do this easily within Photoshop. However, it's fairly simple in Illustrator.

Comment: Hey Scott, since there doesn't seem to be a Photoshop way, could you post an answer with the steps for taking a shape with some added effects from PS and applying them in AI? Something like this: http://i.imgur.com/21kUWpg.png